# Calculate two columns they automatic put into total column

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to create a column within a MySQL structure that automatically sums two other columns?

So if I have a table called TABLE:

`Column A, Column B, and Column C.`

I would want `Column C` to automatically sum `Column A` and `Column B`.

Is that possible?

If A changes, C changes.

If it possible than how.any example if you have.

Comment: Just a heads up: The answer you accepted does not fulfill all your requirements. If you update columnA, columnC will not be updated, rendering it inconsistent. You would have to create an additional trigger to handle the updates.

Comment: But it's working on my side.

Comment: Only if you had a trigger for update, otherwise it can't work. See this: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bf31/1)

Comment: Ammmmm. Can you  write any way to solve this problem please write answer below.or debug answer.

Comment: It's the same as the one you accepted, create a new trigger but change BEFORE INSERT to BEFORE UPDATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER myTableAutoSum
BEFORE INSERT ON `myTable` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.ColumnC = NEW.ColumnA + NEW.ColumnB;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then this query:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (ColumnA, ColumnB) values(1, 1), (2, 3), (1, 4);
```

Will result in rows:

```
ColumnA  ColumnB  ColumnC
1        1        2
2        3        5
1        4        5
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with a VIEW:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (a INT, b INT);  

CREATE
  OR replace VIEW V_TABLE AS
SELECT a, b, a + b AS c
FROM table1;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1557f/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

you need to read about triggers http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

then you will be able to create before insert and before update triggers which will maintain proper value in column C

Comment: I added TRIGGER syntax below. J

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't support computed columns directly. You could use a trigger to compute the column, but you can always retrieve the computed value in your queries:

For example:

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, (ColumnA+ColumnB) as ColumnC from myTable
```